# VB script + replcae word in txt

Tags: vbscript

code , that find in the txt file the line that start with the : THIS_LOCATION
and replace the OFF_LINE with NEW

if InStr(strText  , 'THIS_LOCATION' )  then

strNewText = Replace(strText, "OFF_LINE", "NEW")

End if

the VB script failed on the line :

if InStr(strText  , 'THIS_LOCATION' )

what wrong?

THX
yael

Answer (score 0):

You need double quotes:

```
If InStr(strText, "THIS_LOCATION") Then
```

Comment: OK its work
but its also replace in all txt
my target was to replace only in THIS_LOCATION line
whats wrong?

Comment: If you are using information from my previous answers, it seems that strText contains all your text, rather than a single line. To read a line from a text stream got with the FileSystemObject, use ReadLine, not ReadAll. You can read line by line using `While Not f.AtEndOfStream` where f is the Textstream object.